# error thrown when using su -c: bash: no job control in this shell

Tags: bash, su

I have written a script which should execute certain commands as another user and after execution is finished (success or failure) should logout immediately.

I have read that I can use `-c` of `su` to execute commands. So, I wrote a script like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

su - user2 -c "echo 'hurray' && exit"
```

It executes the `echo` command but stays logged in as `user2` doesn't logout. I even tried using `logout` instead of `exit` but it stays logged in. I need to execute script as `user1` which invokes the `su` command and executes as `user2` and then the control should return to `user1` after completion.

**UPDATE**

Alright, I was to able logout automatically but this time some commands are not being executed. For eg:

Command1:

```
su user2 -c 'echo 1'
```

Output1:

```
1
```

And, then it logs out on its own.

Command2:

```
su user2 -c 'bash some-script.sh'
```

Output2:

```
bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell
```

So, whenever I try to run some script via `-c` of `su`, it displays the above mentioned error. I've tried many commands with `-c` option such as `ls`, `which`, `bash --version`, `mkdir`, `rm`, `whoami` etc. All these commands produced the correct output. But any command which tries to execute a script, it fails with the error.

```
su user2 -c 'bash --version'      # Works
su user2 -c 'bash some-script.sh' # Doesn't work
```

I cannot figure out why this is happening. And, so is the reason I'm unable to fix this error.

Comment: Do you have `su` aliased to anything?  And what is `user2`'s default shell?

Comment: @JigglyNaga No, it is not aliased to anything. Default shell is `bash`

Answer (score 4):

The reason for this behaviour is documented in the manual page for recent versions of `su`:

> -c, --command COMMAND
>
> Specify a command that will be invoked by the shell using its `-c`.
>
> The executed command will **have no controlling terminal**. This option
>   cannot be used to execute interractive  programs which need a controlling
>   TTY.

(emphasis mine)

---

When you run basic commands such as `ls`, `echo` or `bash --version`, they simply print their output to the `stdout` stream without without needing a controlling terminal.

I suspect that either the way `bash` is being invoked (as an interactive shell) or `some-script.sh` contains commands which require a controlling terminal device so running `'bash some-script.sh'` throws the `cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device` error.

#### Some explanation

A **controlling terminal** for a process is the terminal device from which the process was started. A controlling terminal can send signals to groups of process and is the mechanism by which job control works in Unix operating systems; job control allows processes in the process group to be run in foreground or the background.

The output of the `ps` command shows the controlling terminal for each process, e.g.,

```
$ ps

  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 3614 pts/5    00:00:00 bash
31628 pts/5    00:00:00 ps
```

#### Recent change in su

In the past, `su -c` did start a controlling terminal when not running an interactive shell. Running `apt-get changelog login` on my Ubuntu system shows that the removal of the controlling terminal was introduced in May 2012 as a security measure:

> - su: Fix possible tty hijacking by dropping the controlling terminal when
>     executing a command (CVE-2005-4890). Closes: #628843

Comment: So, basically there is now way to execute `bash script.sh` commands via `su`?

Comment: You can use `--session-command` instead of `-c`